# What is an example of a curve segment in $\Bbb R^2$ not of measure $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, riemann-integration

It seems to me that all curve segments in $\Bbb R^2$ are of measure $0$. In other words, they can be covered by a countable set of open rectangles with volume arbitrarily small. Any counter example to that?

Comment: Space-filling curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: @Spenser I think that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @5xum no, it'd get flagged as "link only answer (and not spam)" then deleted.

Comment: @AdamHughes Well, yeah, he should add another sentence or two, but still...